Graph API: Adding app to Microsoft Teams chat returns 403 Forbidden
I have Teams app fully configured and working. I use Graph API to perform different actions from behalf this app.
One of my use-cases is using Graph API to add app to chat as described in this docs.
This request worked good yesterday (with 201 Created response):
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chatId}/installedApps

{"teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{appId}"}

But today in most cases I'm recieving this 403 Forbidden error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Caller is not authorized.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-10-30T09:28:09",
            "request-id": "c4a81d43-4681-4aa1-adb8-d16f874fc948",
            "client-request-id": "c4a81d43-4681-4aa1-adb8-d16f874fc948"
        }
    }
}

I tried to make it with different chat IDs.
I also tested this behavior by sending this request more times (with delays to prevent limits hitting) - sometimes it returns 201 Created, but probability of successful response is about 1%.
I did not change any scopes or permissions or policies for my app.
I have TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForChat.All permission granted and not revoked to my app.
Also I checked my client secret in Azure / Certificates & secrets - and my secret is not expired.
Can someone explain me what else can I check? Or maybe it's an issue on the MS side?

A 'Caller is not authorized' error with the Graph API typically indicates that the identity used to authorize and call the API does not have the necessary permissions to access the requested resource. Could you please re-verify that the app has the correct permissions granted and also consented?
